# Convert Milliseconds to Hours : Minutes : Seconds in Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I am getting a a field called duration_in_milliseconds from an API, is there a function or a way to convert that to hours:minutes:seconds somehow?

I've looked and can't find any solutions. Thanks for any help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@craigster's answer is useful if you want just the number of hours **or** the minutes **or** the seconds represented by the milliseconds.

If you want all three, you need to do a bit more arithmetic.

For instance, 23 hrs 59 mins 55 seconds:

```
  (23 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
+ (59 * 60 * 1000)
+ (55 * 1000)
= 86395000 milliseconds
```

To convert 86395000 back into HH:MM:SS you could do:

```
<cfscript>
hours = int(duration_in_milliseconds \ (60 * 60 * 1000));
mins = (duration_in_milliseconds \ (60 * 1000)) mod 60;
secs = (duration_in_milliseconds \ 1000) mod 60;
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>#hours# #mins# #secs#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Isn't something missing here? If you're starting with milliseconds, the seconds should be a decimal value, and here you're only getting an integer value.

Comment: @newenglander Often you don't care about the milliseconds but only want the second. If you want the milliseconds to be part of the sconds you can use `secs = (duration_in_milliseconds \ 1000) mod 60 + (duration_in_milliseconds mod 1000)/1000`

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is divide it.

duration_in_milliseconds / 1000 = Seconds

duration_in_milliseconds / 60000 = Minutes

(duration_in_milliseconds / 60000) / 60 = Hours

In Coldfusion Code it might look like this

If you want Hours use this line

```
<cfset Hours = (LSParseNumber(duration_in_milliseconds) / 60000) / 60>
```

If you want Minutes use this line

```
<cfset Minutes= LSParseNumber(duration_in_milliseconds) / 60000>
```

If you want Seconds use this line

```
<cfset Seconds= LSParseNumber(duration_in_milliseconds) / 1000>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run this code using 27667 as the milliseconds. I am getting: 0.00768527777778:0.461116666667:27.667. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just use one line for example if you wants seconds. Just use this line: <cfset Seconds= LSParseNumber(duration_in_milliseconds) / 1000>

Comment: Clean solution...Very nice. +1

Answer (score 2):

You should start with this: [`createTimeStruct()`](http://www.cflib.org/udf/CreateTimeStruct), and modify it to support a mask of milliseconds as well.

Don't reinvent the wheel. Just tweak an existing wheel.

Comment: Quite keen to hear from the person who downvoted this..? Not enough detail? I didn't think that reproducing the code made sense, and also thought it would be patronising to explain how to mod the code to work from milliseconds instead of seconds. The main gist of my answer was to *not* write one's own routine if a routine which does what one wants already exists. The lesson - and a good one for most CF developers - is "see what's already out there; don't repeat what others have already done.